# Tensorflow2.x UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported data in tf.data.dataset format with text, numeric & categorical features

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have beginner/intermediate level knowledge of TensorFlow. I have a deep learning model that has text, numeric & categorical inputs. The target is an empirical distribution with 19 bins. The text input is preprocessed initially & tokenized (using `Tokenizer`). Categorical inputs are one-hot encoded using `CategoryEncoding` layer in the model. Please see Data prep steps below.

In the model (please see Model & training below), the tokenized text weighted by a 300-word word2vec embedding in an `Embedding` layer. This is then sent to separate `Conv1D` layers, the output of which is combined with numeric & categorical inputs. Categorical inputs are one-hot encoded [using Keras preprocessing - `CategoryEncoding` layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers#categorical_columns).

I am [converting the input to a tf.data.Dataset format](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers#create_an_input_pipeline_using_tfdata). As text input, encoded using word2vec embedding, is an input to separate layers in the model, I have it as a separate input in the tf Dataset prep. Please see Data prep steps below.

Data prep steps:

```
def get_tf_dataset(
        text_embedding,
        dataframe,
        feature_cols_list,
        target_cols_list,
        batch_size=64
):
    df = dataframe.reset_index().copy()
    target_df = df[target_cols_list]
    aux_input_df = {
        key: value[:, tf.newaxis] for key, value in df[feature_cols_list].items()
    }
    tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (
            (
                tf.convert_to_tensor(text_embedding, dtype=tf.float32),
                dict(aux_input_df)
            ),
            target_df
        )
    )

    return tf_dataset


aux_df = data[categorical_features_list + numeric_features_list + target_cols_list]

train_c = round(data.shape[0] * 0.8)

list_sentences_train = text_data[:train_c]
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(list_sentences_train))
list_tokenized_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(list_sentences_train)
x_train = pad_sequences(list_tokenized_train, maxlen=5)

aux_train = get_tf_dataset(
    x_train, aux_df[:train_c],
    feature_cols_list=numeric_features_list + categorical_features_list,
    target_cols_list=target_cols_list
)
```

Model & training:

```
inp = Input(shape=(5,), name='tokenized_string')
init = Embedding(5, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix])(inp)
x1 = Conv1D(64, 4, activation="relu", padding='same', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(init)

x = GlobalMaxPool1D()(x1)


def get_categorical_encoding_layer(dataset, feature_name):

    index = StringLookup()
    # Get (aux[feature]) from input Tensor in the format of ((embedding, aux), target)
    feature_dataset = dataset.map(lambda a, b: a[1][feature_name])

    index.adapt(feature_dataset)
    encoder = CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=index.vocabulary_size(), output_mode='one_hot')
    return lambda feature: encoder(index(feature))

categorical_encoded_feature_list = []
categorical_col_list = []

for feature in categorical_features_list:
    categorical_col_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string', name=feature)
    encoded_layer = get_categorical_encoding_layer(aux_train, feature)
    encoded_feature = encoded_layer(categorical_col_input)
    categorical_col_list.append(categorical_col_input)
    categorical_encoded_feature_list.append(encoded_feature)

aux_numerical_inp = [Input(shape=(1,), name='f1'), Input(shape=(1,). name='f2')]
aux_inp = [*aux_numerical_inp, *categorical_col_list]
aux_inp_layers = [*aux_numerical_inp, *categorical_encoded_feature_list]

x = concatenate([x, *aux_inp_layers])

x = Dense(1000, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)

model = Model(inputs=[inp, aux_inp], outputs=x)
optimizer = Adam()
model.compile(
    loss='msle',
    optimizer=optimizer
)
model.fit(
    aux_train.batch(64),
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=64,
    validation_data=aux_val,
)
```

I get the following error:

`OP_REQUIRES failed at cast_op.cc:121 : UNIMPLEMENTED: Cast string to float is not supported`.

```
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'model_1/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
```

I am not able to figure out where I am missing something and I have string inputs in categorical features that are supposed to be mapped to one-hot encoded integers through the categorical layer. The input to the categorical layer is also casted as `dtype='string'` like so:
`categorical_col_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string', name=feature)`

Update: I am running this using `tensorflow-macos=2.11.0`. Apparently, [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16101) has been reported for `tensorflow=2.8` for Sequential models. But for functional models dtype is included in the layer definition, as I've done as well.

Would greatly appreciate any thoughts!!